# ts flaten a const assertions array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want const assertions can limit in the same one array item.But it would mixup all array item property.

```js
const subPackages = [
    {
      root: 'pages/common/pages',
      pages: [{ path: '404/index'}],
    },
    {
      root: 'pages/personal/pages',
      pages: [
        { path: 'info/index'},
        { path: 'login/index'},
      ],
    },
] as const
/**
* subPackagesPaths would be assertions as 'pages/common/pages/404/index' | 'pages/common/pages/info/index' | 'pages/common/pages/login/index' | 'pages/common/pages/info/index' ...
*
* I expect it can be assertions as 'pages/common/pages/404/index' | 'pages/personal/pages/info/index' | *'pages/personal/pages/login/index'
*/
const subPackagesPaths = subPackages.flatMap((sub) => {
  return sub.pages.map((item) => `${sub.root}/${item.path}` as const)
})
```

I try it

```js
type subPackagesPaths = `${(typeof subPackages)[number]['root']}/${(typeof subPackages)[number]['page'][number]['path']}`
```

but no work

Comment: It's just a typo: https://tsplay.dev/WYL03m

Answer (score 0):

After deeply learning of TS I find a way to keep nest object's value in type.

```
const pageJson = {
  pages: [
    {
      path: 'pages/index/index',
    },
    {
      path: 'pages/my/index',
    },
  ],
  subPackages: [
    {
      root: 'pages/index',
      pages: [
        {
          path: 'login/index',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      root: 'pages/my',
      pages: [
        {
          path: 'info/index',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  tabBar: {
    list: [
      {
        pagePath: 'pages/index/index',
        text: '首页',
      },
      {
        pagePath: 'pages/my/index',
        text: '我的',
      },
    ],
  },
} as const

type PagesConfig = typeof pageJson
type subPackages = PagesConfig['subPackages'][number]
type UnwrapPath<T> = T extends subPackages
  ? `/${T['root']}/${T['pages'][number]['path']}`
  : never
export type subPackagePagesPath = UnwrapPath<subPackages>
export default pageJson
```

It can give right type tips.